# Using Pointers in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save a reference into a memory location. According to my limited C# knowledge that means a pointer. When i try to do that I get multiple errors. Like I mentioned i'm new to C#. Help is appreciated.
obviously the code is in a namespace and stuff

```
unsafe internal static class GooseAngerVars
{
   public static float DropDistanceVar = 40f;
   fixed (public static float* DropDistancePoint = &DropDistanceVar);
}
```

```
unsafe private struct Task_NabMouse
{
   public static float* MouseDropDistance = GooseAngerVars.DropDistancePoint;
}
```

If i should be using `ref` a example would be great so i don't have too google it latter

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: What kind of C# program are you working on *"that requires the use of pointers"*. If you don't understand that error, you don't understand what "pointers" mean in C#'s world, and I suspect that your assumption that you require pointers is incorrect.  You should realize that variables of types that are reference types act a lot like pointers in unmanaged code. If you pass `ref` or `out` parameters to methods, they are pointer-like as well (and, if they are of reference type, they are like pointers to pointers)

Comment: I want to use a pointer to save a reference into a variable. That might not be what i need to do because im probably trying to think about this from a c++ point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to shed your C++ thought processes and start thinking like a C# programmer, you need to understand the type system.

In C++, `struct` and `class` are nearly synonyms.  They are very different in C#. A `struct` defines a *Value Type* while a `class` defines a *Reference Type*. The biggest difference between the two is what assignment means. When you do Value Type assignment, the value is copied. During Reference Type assignment, the reference to an existing object is copied (or *null* is copied).

As a note, many "built-in" types (like the numeric types, `int`  `double`, etc) are structs under the covers (look up `System.Int32`).

So, assuming the `Point` type is a Value Type, in ...

```
var p1 = new Point (3, 4);
var p2 = p1;
p1.X =42;
```

A new Point object is created and its value is copied to `p1`. Then that same value is copied to `p2`. Finally, the `X` property of `p1` is set to 42. But, since each of `p1` and `p2` hold different values, `p2.X` remains at 3.

Now, let's assuming there's a class called CPoint (so it's a Reference Type) and we have nearly the same code.

```
var p1 = new CPoint (3, 4);
var p2 = p1;
p1.X =42;
```

Here, `p1` is a reference to the newly created `CPoint` object. The assignment copies that reference to `p2`. At point, both variables refer (*point*) to the same object (that was created on the *managed heap*). So, when the `p1.X` assignment is executed, the object `p1` refers to is mutated,  and that mutation is seen through the `p2` variable as well.

As a C++ programmer, this should look familiar (all that's missing is a `*`). Of course, since .NET is garbage collected/managed, you don't need to worry about who *owns* the object and how you are going to `delete` the `CPoint` you created.

If you want to hold a reference to a float, wrap it in a class, and you can forget about pointers and `unsafe`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers is not recommended by default, but it is the same as in C or C++, and you have to signal it as unsafe. The word unsafe says something.

Using ref is simpler.

It does almost the same:

```
Struct C1
{
  public int v1;
}

Class C2 
{
  public C2()
  {
    var c1 = new C1();
    //  You must ensure to mark it as ref when passing it as argument
    //  This enforces you are aware that the function may mess with your variable
    DoSomethingWithC1(ref c1);
    //  c1.v1 is changed after function call
    Console.WriteLine(c1.v1.toString());
  }
  //  Define at function signature that it must pass a reference
  //  If you don't mark it as a reference a new variable is created (see Flydog57 answer)
  void DoSomethingWithC1(ref C1 c1)
  {
    //Here c1 is a reference, you are actually manipulating the same c1 as in C2 constructor
    c1.v1 = 33;
  }
}
```